# Bootstrap 3 cards with same height and width CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

I have bootstrap 3 cards in my shop, however my problem is that it is not with the same height and width if its in mobile view.

[image]

[image]

What I need is IT to be aligned and have the exact same width and height when viewed in a mobile.

**This is my css code for the cards:**

```
/* EXAMPLE 1 - BOOTSTRAP FLEXBOX
   - Equal Height Columns in Rows
   - Equal Height Thumbnails
   - Flex Grow to Fill Paragraph Height
*/

/* Flexbox Equal Height Bootstrap Columns (fully responsive) */
@media only screen and (min-width : 500px) {
  .flex-row.row {
    display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flex-row.row > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .flex-row.row:after, 
  .flex-row.row:before {
   display: flex;
  }
  .flex-row.row > [class*='col-'] > .box {
   display: flex;
   flex: 1;
  }
}

/* Grow thumbnails to fill columns height */
.flex-row .thumb,
.flex-row .caption {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Flex Grow Text Container */
.flex-row .caption p.flex-text {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/* Flex Responsive Image */
.flex-row img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.thumb{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.caption{

}
/* EXAMPLE 2 - CSS TABLES EQUAL HEIGHT
   - ie9 support 
   - not responsive (mobile fallback)
*/

.table-row.row,
.table-row-equal {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.table-row.row [class*="col-"] {
  width: 25%;
}
.table-row.row [class*="col-"],
.table-row-equal .thumb {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.table-row-equal {
  border-spacing: 30px 0px;
}
.table-row-equal .thumb {
  width: 1%;
}
/* mobile fallback to support partial responsiveness */
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .table-row-equal .thumb {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* MASONARY BOOTSTRAP 3 GRID
   - Who needs V4?
*/
.masonary-row.row {
  -webkit-column-gap: 30px;
  column-gap: 30px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-column-fill: balance;
          column-fill: balance;
}
.masonary-row [class*="col-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: none;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-column-fill: balance;
          column-fill: balance;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .masonary-row.row {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masonary-row.row {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}
/* demo */
.bootflex .well {
      flex-grow: 1;
  }

/* pre hack for small devices */
pre {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.flex-row.flex-code.row > [class*='col-'] .flex-text {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.overview {
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.card-default {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card-default>* {
  width: 100%;
}

.excludingImage {
  align-self: flex-end;
  text-align: center;
}

/* End Added */

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 6px;

}

.card>.card-link {
  color: #333;
}

.card>.card-link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card>.card-link .card-img img {
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
.card .card-body {
  /* display: table;
  width: 100%; */
  padding: 12px;
}

.card .card-header {
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  padding: 8px;
}
.card .card-footer {
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

**and this is code for my HTML card:**

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumb">
        <div class="caption card card-default">
            <div class="card-img">
                <img src="user_images/<?php echo $row['userPic'] ?>" alt="Card image" class="img-thumbnail" height="100">
            </div>
            <div class="excludingImage">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text" style="color:#00873a"><b><?php echo $cartname ?></b></p>
                    <p class="card-text" style="color:#e81b30">
                        <strike style="color:#aaa">₱<?php echo $orig ?>.00</strike> ₱<?php echo $cartprice ?>.00
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    <a href="shopview.php?prod=<?php echo $cartname ?>">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-pink btn-sm">
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> View Product 
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem you have there (according to your images) is that your product image is bigger in the problematic card. You could add a constraint to the card itself, though that would cut off your `View product` button. Do you just want to shrink the image?

Comment: I'd like to shrink the image if the card is going to be in same height and width

Comment: If you could provide a JSFiddle I can look into this. if its still not sorted

Comment: @NifalMunzir Hi this is my JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eyfdv0k7/ I really need it to be on same width and height even if the image have different sizes. Thanks a lot..

Comment: @NifalMunzir the problem is if its in mobile view, the card is not on same height and width

Comment: @Angela Please take a look at my answer for a javascript solution also please update your JSFiddle with html source as your fiddle currently has php code as well

Comment: @Angela I updated fiddle with some sample images. Please check if this is what you are expecting https://jsfiddle.net/zac5kvq9/

Comment: @NifalMunzir will check into it, i'll update you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the images you are loading and the text of every product. If the image for every card is not the same height, that will push the height of each individual card. The same goes for the text of each card, if the name of the product overflows to a second line, it will push the height of the card.

Comment: I'd like to shrink the image if the card is going to be in same height and width

Comment: If you shrink the image to be the same height and width then the image will be distorted. There are a couple solutions you can use but to be honest the easiest is to use images with the same width and height dimensions or ratios i.e. (1x1, 4x3, etc)

Comment: I see :) thanks a lot!! will just have all images uploaded to be on exact ratios!

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [Match Height](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height), if you are fine with a javascript solution.

It basically gets the maximum height of the given selector and then applies to all matching elements

**Sample:**

```
$(function() { 
    $('.card_wrapper_class').matchHeight(); 
});
```